# Select JOIN + AVG() - Duvida com retorno

Tags: mysql, join, count

Estou resolvendo um exercício porem estou com problemas no retorno:

**Pergunta:**
Escreva a consulta que retorna o código do fornecedor, o nome do fornecedor, o número de produtos por fornecedor e o preço médio para cada fornecedor, apenas para fornecedores que tenham um desconto médio maior do que 0.10. O resultado deve estar ordenado pelo preço médio.

**Criação das tabelas:**

[image: Tabela FORNECEDOR]

[image: Tabela PRODUTO]

Preciso retornar o select acima, porém não estou conseguindo por 2 motivos:

Retornar a media de preco para cada fornecedor usando a função AVG(parametro).

Retornar a quantidade de produtos por fornecedor, estou usando o COUNT().

Meu select até agora:

```
    SELECT f.codigo, f.nome, AVG(p.preco), COUNT(codfornecedor)
    FROM produto as p
    JOIN fornecedor as f
    on codfornecedor = f.codigo AND p.desconto > 10 ORDER BY p.preco ASC
```

Com o método de seleção acima ele está retornando o preço médio de todos os campos, o que eu não quero, preciso que retorne o preço médio de cada fornecedor, bem como sua quantidade de produtos.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar nesta consulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer o `AVG` para cada fornecedor você precisa usar o `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT f.codigo, f.nome, AVG(p.preco), COUNT(codfornecedor)
FROM produto as p
JOIN fornecedor as f on codfornecedor = f.codigo
WHERE p.desconto > 0.10
GROUP BY f.codigo
ORDER BY p.preco ASC
```

Comment: Obrigado Roberto de Campos, vou estudar mais a respeito do GROUP BY, interessante.